# Activating custom feature using FBA in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

I've created a feature with a custom feature receiver for a site in sharepoint, using forms based authentication.

However, whenever I try and activate the feature (even though the forms based account has top privileges) I get a 403 - "Requires you to be logged in".

I can activate and deactivate other features just fine, just not my custom one. Is there a special trick to creating features with a feature receiver allowing me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently full admin-impersonation and RunWithElevatedPrivileges did the trick.

Here's the code for anyone interested (goes in the FeatureActivated/-Deactivated methods):

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    SPWeb _web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb; 
    SPUserToken sysAdmin = _web.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(_web.Site.ID, sysAdmin)) {
        using (SPWeb web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(_web.ID)) {
            //Code goes here...
        }
    }
});
```